# .NET 5 ASP.NET Core App not starting in Azure

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, .net-5

I am trying to host a .NET 5 ASP.NET Core Web Api in Azure. Unfortunately the app is not starting as the "Diagnose Problems" is also seeing. Looks like it's stuck in a starting loop, because I get the same messages in the Log stream over and over:

```
2020-11-13T11:25:43 Start 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureAppServices.SiteExtension' site extension transform
2020-11-13T11:25:44 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 7, 23)
2020-11-13T11:25:44 on /configuration/system.webServer
2020-11-13T11:25:44 Applying to 'configuration' element (no source line info)
2020-11-13T11:25:44 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2020-11-13T11:25:44 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 8, 16)
2020-11-13T11:25:44 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime
2020-11-13T11:25:44 Applying to 'system.webServer' element (no source line info)
2020-11-13T11:25:44 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2020-11-13T11:25:44 StartSection Executing InsertIfMissing (transform line 9, 31)
2020-11-13T11:25:44 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime/environmentVariables
2020-11-13T11:25:44 Applying to 'runtime' element (no source line info)
2020-11-13T11:25:44 EndSection Done executing InsertIfMissing
2020-11-13T11:25:44 StartSection Executing InsertOrAppendAttribute (transform line 10, 406)
2020-11-13T11:25:44 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime/environmentVariables/add[@name='DOTNET_ADDITIONAL_DEPS']
2020-11-13T11:25:44 Applying to 'environmentVariables' element (no source line info)
2020-11-13T11:25:44 EndSection Done executing InsertOrAppendAttribute
2020-11-13T11:25:44 StartSection Executing InsertOrAppendAttribute (transform line 11, 158)
2020-11-13T11:25:44 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime/environmentVariables/add[@name='DOTNET_SHARED_STORE']
2020-11-13T11:25:44 Applying to 'environmentVariables' element (no source line info)
2020-11-13T11:25:44 EndSection Done executing InsertOrAppendAttribute
2020-11-13T11:25:44 StartSection Executing InsertOrAppendAttribute (transform line 12, 146)
2020-11-13T11:25:44 on /configuration/system.webServer/runtime/environmentVariables/add[@name='ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES']
2020-11-13T11:25:44 Applying to 'environmentVariables' element (no source line info)
2020-11-13T11:25:44 EndSection Done executing InsertOrAppendAttribute
2020-11-13T11:25:44 Successful 'C:\home\SiteExtensions\Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureAppServices.SiteExtension\applicationHost.xdt' site extension transform
2020-11-13T11:25:44 sandboxproc.exe complete successfully. Elapsed = 1208.00 ms
2020-11-13T11:25:56 sandboxproc.exe D:\DWASFiles\Sites\fotoapp-api\Temp\applicationhost.config True True
2020-11-13T11:25:57 env XPROC_TYPENAME=Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Transformers.ApplicationHost.SiteExtensionHelper, Microsoft.Web.Hosting, Version=7.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
2020-11-13T11:25:57 env XPROC_METHODNAME=Transform
<these messages repeat endlessly>
```

I tried framework-dependent deployment (with .NET 5 runtime enabled in the app service) and also self-contained deployment.

I can't find better logs anywhere. Application Insights is not yet supported.

Requests to the api don't get through to the log stream. After ~2 minutes the server responds with "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable".

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Quick web search says it's a non-common problem, but you're not the first one to get it, nor the last since I got it last week, same exact issue basically. It's still not solved, and Microsoft refuses to acknowledge that the problem even exists.

Comment: My solution was to run it in a docker container. Sounds kind of stupid but with the added layer everything just ran. The docker tooling is great, I just followed the functions in VS to add Docker to a web application. @LinusProxy

Comment: Actually a good suggestion. It's not stupid to control your own runtime instead of relying on a third rate runtime hosting partner.

Comment: To add to my workaround: Now that docker changed its license, just running everything in containers might not be the solution for everybody.
On the other hand, the SDK is much more stable now and I managed to deploy .NET 5 apps to Azure easily without the need for a container workaround. Also .NET 6 is now out..

Answer (score 1):

I also had this error.

In my case the problem was somehow related to the **Azure App Service 64-bit / 32-bit** platform settings ( *Web App \ Configuration \ General settings \ Platform settings* ).

I had recently changed it to 64-bit and then started getting this error, when I reverted back to 32-bit the problem went away.

I have not determined the root cause, but for what it's worth, there it is.